# VScode shows an error when having multiple Go Projects in a directory

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

When opening a directory in VSCode that consists of multiple Go projects the following error appears:

```
gopls requires a module at the root of your workspace.
You can work with multiple modules by opening each one as a workspace folder.
Improvements to this workflow will be coming soon (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32394),
and you can learn more here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36899.
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 103):

**Go 1.18+**

From Go 1.18 onwards there is native support for multi-module workspaces.
This is done by having a `go.work` file present in your parent directory.

For a directory structure such as:

```bash
$ tree /my/parent/dir
/my/parent/dir
├── project-one
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── project-one.go
│   └── project-one_test.go
└── project-two
    ├── go.mod
    ├── project-two.go
    └── project-two_test.go
```

Create and populate the file by executing `go work`:

```bash
cd /my/parent/dir
go work init
go work use project-one
go work use project-two
```

This will add a `go.work` file in your parent directory that contains a list of directories you marked for usage:

```
go 1.18

use (
    ./project-one
    ./project-two
)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for Go1.18+ code issues. Here is the source for the answer https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md

Comment: this is amazing.. solved my problem for go v20

Comment: From my experience, `go.work` support is not yet a fully baked feature as [not all Go tooling commands support go.work](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50750) - I am currently figuring out how to use `go.mod` replacements instead.  Reverting to the Go model before go.work appears simpler than fighting with go.work support.

Comment: For VS Code, `/my/parent/dir` should be the workspace root. Ref: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/2534#issuecomment-1321922111

Answer (score 87):

You probably have more than one go module in your workspace. If that is the case, you can change the go extension settings, in order to allow gopls to look for multiple modules in the workspace. Just add the following to your `settings.json`:

```
"gopls": {
    "experimentalWorkspaceModule": true,
}
```

You can read more about `gopls` configuration in the docs: https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/settings.md

Comment: This is a good answer, especially for new learners setting up multiple workspaces while learning, different chapters for a book etc.

Comment: Note: Remember to save it and restart VSCode. "Settings" menu is a sub-menu of "Preferences".

Comment: doesn't it work only for go 1.18?

Comment: the use of  `"gopls": { "experimentalWorkspaceModule": true, }` is depricated as of now and the approached shared by @1ko below will be the way to use now

Comment: After this vscode says: Invalid settings: gopls setting "experimentalWorkspaceModule" is deprecated

Answer (score 56):

To solve this, follow below steps :

step 1 :  Open Vscode, and then go to settings.

step 2 : In the search bar , type gopls

step 3 : Just below that you will find settings.json, click on that

step 4 : Paste the below code their
"gopls": {
"experimentalWorkspaceModule": true,
}

step 5 : Save it and restart the Vscode, You are good to go now.

Comment: After doing this vscode says: Invalid settings: gopls setting "experimentalWorkspaceModule" is deprecated

Answer (score 9):

The setting has changed, now you need to use:

```
"gopls": {
    "build.experimentalWorkspaceModule": true,
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Just run `go mod init your_module_mane`. This command work for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error because I had **not created my modules inside a `src`** directory. So I had:

```
$GOPATH
   -> bin
   -> pkg
   -> github.com
      -> Module
         -> go.mod
```

and that needed to be:

```
$GOPATH
   -> bin
   -> pkg
   -> src
       -> github.com
          -> Module
            -> go.mod
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply Open the terminal:-

```
go mod init poc
```

Here "poc" could be anything related to your project name

Answer (score 3):

I just closed my vscode folder and re-opened it and it resolved the issue. no more action was required.

Comment: Please try to suggest a more technical approach to the question as the proposed solution does not carry a sign of working the same on different devices

Comment: @erpe it was smart VS Code setting detection that resolved the issue! sorry no more feedback I remember. sometimes restarting your env can resolve the issue

Comment: it showed also errors for me and they were only gone after i restarted my vscode ...

Answer (score 3):

I installed the latest go "go version go1.20.5 linux/amd64" and fixed it by running the following command in my work directory

```
cd $<your work directory>
go work init
go work use ./tools/ ./tools/gopls/
```

Refer : https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md

Answer (score 2):

This is working now...

```
"gopls": {
    "build.experimentalWorkspaceModule": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your project folder where main.go file is located in cmd type

```
code .
```

this will open new VS Code in that folder

Comment: this is it, thank you +1

Answer (score 0):

Add `go.work` file in the root of the folder and define modules as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not the perfect solution but it is good as temporay one In my case I had a react project and a go project opened under the same root what solved my problem is opening each project is a separate window.

Answer (score 0):

there are so many beautiful answers here!
The shortest way is:
simply open the **terminal in Vs Code** from your **working directory** and enter the following command in the root of your working directory:
`go work init`
This will initialize the working directory!

Answer (score -1):

go version go1.21.1 windows/amd64

please go to source code parent dir(parent dir of your modules)

go work init ( this will create go.work file in your root dir)

go work use mod1 ( it will add module1 to go.work file)

go work use mod2 (it will add the module2 to go.work file)