# Error message "go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'"

Tags: linux, go

I just updated to the new version of Go - Go version 1.16.2 Linux/amd64 and am getting an error when I build a [Hello, World! example](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1):

> go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'

Even when I follow the fix from [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66740187/errors-running-first-go-project-on-local-machine) it isn't working. I set these variables and then build again:

```
GO111MODULE=on
GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
```

And the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: Did you run `go mod init` as shown in [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code), [Getting Started](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started), or [Creating a Module](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/create-module)?

Comment: Read and stick to https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started. You must use modules in Go 1.16.

Comment: In what context are *GO111MODULE* and *GOPROXY* set? Inside file *go.mod*? Or somewhere else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It should be set in your shell. It could be in a shells script too.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Yes, just follow the tutorial and for me that was doing `go mod init test3` to create a module.  No one else has been upgrading from the old version or everyone else just understood it properly I guess.

Comment: Thank you! This works as building a docker image too - `RUN go mod init` in a `Dockerfile` :)

Comment: Thanks, this was counterintuitive to me.

Answer (score 293):

Change this:

`go env -w GO111MODULE=auto`

to this:

`go env -w GO111MODULE=off`

Comment: it worked man thanks but can you explain why it works ?

Comment: this worked. thanks.. should be included in the documentation on github

Comment: GO111MODULE=off forces Go to behave the GOPATH way, even outside of GOPATH

Comment: Read more about it here : https://maelvls.dev/go111module-everywhere/

Comment: this really works

Comment: This should be the answer, it is a one-liner, works, and is very clear on what it says to do.

Comment: Why does this work? What is it supposed to do? Are there some security implications of this change? What is the theory of operation?

Comment: First make sure that your GO111MODULE value is set to "auto". You can check it from:

```bash
go env

```

if it is not set to "auto", run:

```bash
go env -w GO111MODULE=auto

```

go to your work directory in terminal and run:

```bash
go mod init 'project_name'
go mod tidy

```

set to "off" again, or else your code won't run, to do so, run:

```bash
go env -w GO111MODULE=off
```

You are good to Go!

Answer (score 88):

First make sure that your GO111MODULE value is set to "auto".
You can check it from:

```
go env
```

If it is not set to "auto", then run:

```
go env -w GO111MODULE=auto
```

Go to your work directory in terminal and run:

```
go mod init
go mod tidy
```

You are good to go!

Comment: `go mod init` leads to `go: cannot determine module path for source directory d:\TMSU (outside GOPATH, module path must be specified)`.

Comment: @pmor you need to specify the file path with the command , use `go mod init ~/path_to_file.go`

Comment: this gives me $GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not

Answer (score 21):

From your project directory, add this line of code in your `Dockerfile` file if you are building a Docker image:

`RUN go mod init`

Or this in your directory:

`go mod init`

Answer (score 12):

Go builds packages in module-aware mode by default starting from 1.16. See [here](https://blog.golang.org/go116-module-changes).

Navigate to the folder containing the Go file and run:

`go mod init <modulename>`.

A *go.mod* file is created here and this directory will become the root of the newly created module. See [here](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) to read about Go modules.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
FROM golang:alpine

WORKDIR /go/src/app

ADD . .
RUN go mod init

RUN go build  -o /helloworld

EXPOSE 6111

CMD ["./helloworld"]
```

Comment: [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29)-related, presumably? How does that answer the question? What is "`EXPOSE 6111`" supposed to do? Why do `GO111MODULE` and `GOPROXY` not appear in this answer? What version of Docker and which host system (incl. version) was this tested on? Can you [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68158579/edit) in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to run the `go build` command on my Windows local machine and I ran into the `go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'` error.

This is how I went about solving it:

- First I got the root directory of my application by running `$ pwd` and got a response like so `/c/projects/go-projects/go-server`
- Then I ran `$ go mod init c/projects/go-projects/go-server`

This totally took away the error and I was able to run the server with the command `$ ./go-web`

*PS*: It is important to note that I was running Linux commands on my machine using the [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) Linux terminal for Windows, it comes by default in Windows with the installation of git for windows.

Comment: Thank you @Marcel for sharing this solution. I fixed my same error in this way.

Answer (score 4):

**Try running the below commands**

- '*go mod init example.com/m*' to initialize a v0 or v1 module
- '*go mod init example.com/m/v2*' to initialize a v2 module

Answer (score 3):

1. *Do not* install Go in your home folder. E.g. `~/go`, because this folder will be used by To in further third party libraries' installation
2. download and unzip the Go install ZIP file to another place, e.g. `/workspace/tools/go` and set your `PATH=/workspace/tools/go/bin`

That's it. There isn't any need to do `go mod init`.

Answer (score 3):

I am using go **v1.18**. My problem was `go work init`.
See here for more detail:
[VScode show me the error after I install the proxy in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65748509/vscode-show-me-the-error-after-i-install-the-proxy-in-vscode)

I had to do:

```
$ cd /my/parent/dir
$ go work init
$ go work use project-one
$ go work use project-two
```

Now I can do:

```
$ cd {root directory of the module where go.mod is}
$ cd ./project-one
$ go build .
$ go run .
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. I had missed doing `go work use my-project-one`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when I build a Docker image:

```
docker build . -t ms-c3alert:1.0.6
```

Error detail:

```
Step 11/21 : ENV GO111MODULE=on

 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1f1728be0f4a
Step 12/21 : RUN CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o c3alert .
 ---> Running in ee4b3d33d1d2
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
The command '/bin/sh -c CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o c3alert .' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I've resolved it by adding the following lines in my Dockerfile. Previously, it required to have a Go project in modules, according the guide in previous posts:

```
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently discovered that the "no required module" ***is the error message you get when trying to run/build a Go-file that doesn't exist or has a typo.***

My student had named his file 'filename.Go'. The capital 'G' made it an invalid Go file, but [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) still recognized it as a Go file, so it took a long time to discover it.

I spent a loooong time figuring this out, trying to understand modules and the relationship to folders, when the problem was a typo.

A confusing error message when it was actually the Go file, and not the *.mod* file that was "missing".

Answer (score 1):

just go to the parent directory and run `go mod init "child/project root directory name"`

Answer (score 0):

FROM golang:1.20.5-alpine

```
WORKDIR /app

COPY main.go .

RUN go mod init main
RUN go build -o test.go

CMD ["./test.go"]
```

Change from `RUN go mod init` to `RUN go mod init main` else you will get

> go: cannot determine module path for source directory /app (outside
> GOPATH, module path must be specified)

Answer (score 0):

for me it just remove or disable zsh-golang plugin. https://github.com/wintermi/zsh-golang