# How to run go file on vscode?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I can't run the go program on vscode on my Win11 computer (**no run button, pressing Ctrl+F5 or F5 doesn't work**,like this:
[vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAmcR.jpg)
) and I can't debug it. It's not written on FAQ.

It works on my other Win10 PC. All dependencies are installed

This is my settings.json:

```
    "go.autocompleteUnimportedPackages": true,
    "go.gocodePackageLookupMode": "go",
    "go.gotoSymbol.includeImports": true,
    "go.useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggest": true,
    "go.inferGopath": false,
    "go.gopath": "F:\\vscodefiles\\src\\hello",
    "go.goroot": "D:\\go\\",
    "go.useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggestWithoutType": true,
```

why is this?

Comment: What do you mean by "pressing Ctrl+F5 or F5 doesn't work"? Do you see any error message? Run button should be visible from the "Run and Debug" view (if you don't see the view, find "View: Show Run And Debug" command from the command palette).

Answer (score 2):

Besides installing [Go](https://go.dev) locally, for VSCode you need to install the correct extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=golang.Go

You can install this extension by navigating to "**Extensions**" with:

Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>

MacOS: <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>

Then searching for "**go**" which is by author "**Go Team at Google**"

When you navigate back to your code, you can now press <kbd>F5</kbd> to trigger a debugging run.

---

**Note** when pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> pay attention to the bottom right as you may be prompted to install further dependencies (I had to install 3 more)

I also needed to execute this in a terminal as I kept seeing "no go.mod detected in the current directory"

```bash
go env -w GO111MODULE=off
```

as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67598174)

Answer (score 1):

Try in the terminal:

```
go run myfirstprogram.go
```

[image]

Remember to install Go on your computer before, you can download it from its official page: https://go.dev/ and restart Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I'm already install go,and My Terminal can run'go run myfirstprogram.go'. I'm already install all the go tools.

Comment: This isn't running **from Vscode** Run options